# Bluetooth LE advertisements on VirtualBox with Android-x86

Tags: android, virtual-machine, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-x86

As Android emulator does not support Bluetooth at all, I'm trying to use Android-x86 (android-x86-6.0-r2.iso) on VirtualBox to emulate a Bluetooth LE (low energy, Bluetooth 4) peripheral device.

Unfortunately,

```
advertiser = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();
```

always returns null.

**Is this a problem of VirtualBox, the dongle or Android-x86? Can it be fixed?**

I tried also on current RemixOS (Remix_OS_for_PC_Android_M_32bit_B2016112201) and got the same results. I have tried also VMWare with Android-x86 - the same results.

The dongle is CSR8510 A10 attached to the host (Windows 10) OS. The dongle itself supports Bluetooth advertising - I can discover its advertisements from real Android and iOS devices when running Windows BLE advertising [code samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothAdvertisement). It just does not work on Android-x86 inside VirtualBox.